# horizontal scroll bar with 100% width

Tags: css

I want to have some list items (floated) with 100% width.

The number of list items is arbitrary, it could be 1 or 2, or it could be 20 or 30.

When there are more items than can fit in 100% width of the page, I want it to have a scroll bar to scroll through.

This is what I am currently using, but it doesn't create the scroll. I am guessing I need to set a width for overflow to work, but I want the width to be 100%.

```
.scroll {overflow-x:scroll;}
.scroll li {float:left}

<div class="scroll">
   <ul>
       <li>item 1</li>
       <li>item 2</li>
       <li>item 3</li>
       <li>item 4</li>
       <div stye="clear:both"></div>
   </ul>
</div>
```

So how can I keep a 100% width, with an horizontal scroll?

Comment: possible duplicate of [background css 100% width horizontal scroll issue](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17565422/background-css-100-width-horizontal-scroll-issue)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Horizontal Scrolling?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3574769/horizontal-scrolling)

Comment: `overflow:scroll-x;` is not valid CSS - `overflow-x:scroll;` is, except in Firefox. Specs are messy at this point and Mozilla is playing strict while IE and Webkit both support separate X and Y definitions.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Add `white-space: nowrap` to `.scroll ul`

```
.scroll {overflow:auto; }
.scroll ul{ white-space: nowrap;}
.scroll li {display: inline-block;}
```

**JS Fiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/f6CRt/

Answer (score 0):

Don't use float at all. Floated elements are block level, and **white-space: nowrap;**, which causes text to go off screen, only works for inline elements -- Here's a  [possible duplicate of your question...](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11727900/nav-bar-wrapping-on-smaller-resolutions)

So basically use:

```
.scroll {
  display: block;
  overflow: scroll;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
.scroll li {
  display: inline;
}
```

[Here's a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gvxx4/1/)